# Extended Wpf Toolkit: TableView.Theme broken in version 2.4?

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

Having installed "Extended Wpf Toolkit" (Community Edition) via NuGet in Visual Studio 2013 Professional in a certain project, an update attempt to the current version 2.4 is causing a `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException` at runtime with the same code that previously worked well in version 2.3 here.

As it turned out, that exception is being caused by an `xcdg:TableView Theme` property assignment, see also the repro sample pasted below.

And removing that assignment would cure the symptom.

Since I was unable to find anything on that issue in the web, the actual question probably is whether there is a way to apply DataGridControl / TableView Themes with "Extended WPF Toolkit" Community Edition version 2.4?

The following simplified version reproduces the issue for me in the MainWindow.xaml of a "test" project after having installed the current version 2.4 of Extended WPF Toolkit via NuGet and starting via F5 key:

```
<Window x:Class="testXceed24.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xcdg="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <xcdg:DataGridControl>
            <xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
                <xcdg:TableView Theme="ZuneNormalColorTheme"/>
            </xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
        </xcdg:DataGridControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

FWIW, as a cross-check, downgrading the Extended.Wpf.Toolkit version via Package Manager Console apparently also cures the symptom here:

```
PM> Update-Package Extended.Wpf.Toolkit -Version 2.3.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When that project was continued later, adding a project reference to "Presentationframework.Luna", with Properties -> "Copy Local = "True", turned out to cure the symptom in this particular case (after updating Extended.Wpf.Toolkit from Version 2.3.0 to 2.8.0)